# How to make push notification open chrome app on click? (Node.js, Web-push)

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, web-push

Im using web-push to implement push notifications on my web app, im trying to figure out how to make chrome app open (or the browser they are using) when they click on it. So right now the best I could do was that onclick it will open a link which I dont like since it opens a new tab with the app and I start receiving duplicate notifications.

```
console.log("Service Worker Loaded...");
    var usuario
    self.addEventListener("push", e => {
        const data = e.data.json();
        usuario = data.usuario
    
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
            icon: "/images/icon.png"
        });
    });
    
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
        event.notification.close();
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow('https://fimsa-sistema-vales.herokuapp.com/vales/' + usuario));
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also very new but i found this that could help try pasting this code

```
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();

    // This looks to see if the current is already open and
    // focuses if it is
    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
        type: "window"
    }).then(function(clientList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
            var client = clientList[i];
            if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)
                return client.focus();
        }
        if (clients.openWindow)
            return clients.openWindow('/');
    }));
```

i got it from [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/notificationclick_event``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/notificationclick_event%60%60)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`self.clients.openWindow()` method will open the link in a new tab.
To find out if there's an existing tab already open try the below code. It works on Android Chrome (Haven't tested it on iOS).

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    console.log(`On notification click: ${event.notification.tag}`);
    event.notification.close();

async function handleNotification(event) {
    try {
      // Get the first window client
      const existingClient = await self.clients
          .matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true })
          .then(function (windowClients) {
              return windowClients.length
                ? windowClients[0]
                : self.Promise.reject('No clients!');
           });

      // Check if there's already a window/tab open with the target URL
      if (existingClient)
        // It's already open, let's focus it
        existingClient.focus();

      // It's not open, let's open it first and focus it
      else {
        const client = await self.clients.openWindow(
          event.notification.data.url || '/'
        );
        await client.focus();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors, e.g., unable to focus the client
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }

  // Call the async function in the event handler
  event.waitUntil(handleNotification(event));
});
```